# Nuxt3 useLazyFetch's and useFetch's key property isn't working

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I am using useLazy fetch in a very simple two page application, i have passed a constant string as a key to useLazyFetch, but upon navigating to profile page and coming back to index page it again fetches the data.

pages/index.vaue

```
<template>
    <div v-if="listPending">{{ listPending }}</div>
    <div v-else>{{ countryList }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>

const URL = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=5";

let {pending: listPending, data: countryList} = useLazyFetch(`${URL}/countryList`, {
    key: URL
});

</script>
```

pages/profile.vue

```
<template>
  Profile Page
</template>
```

and below is the layouts/default.vue i use this to navigate between pages

```
<template>
    <div>
        <NuxtLink to="/">Dashboard</NuxtLink>
        <NuxtLink to="profile">Profile</NuxtLink>
    </div>

    <slot/>
</template>
```

am i using the key option in a wrong way ? i also tried passing `key="qwerty"`, but it still refetches the data upon page navigation.

You can test it out here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-w27vnn

Comment: Discussion Here:
https://discord.com/channels/473401852243869706/1098270519075291237